# Stuck at boot screen 12.04

Tags: unity, boot, encryption, lightdm, gdm

I tried to install a lightdm greeter theme but after dissapointing results I chose to try `gdm` instead, which prety much reconfigured my desktop theme, so I chose to remove them both. Since the last boot the computer gets stuck at the boot screen (whom always to happened to show **"could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 M for manual S for skip"** for a while, which I always just could ignore:
[image: Ubuntu boot screen]
Which shows no Hard Disk activity after a while. Waiting for 5 minutes and it still not booting I tried to work around it by:

1. Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to enter CLI, Logging in from the CLI and running `startx`.
2. This presents me the desktop interface without Unity, so I opened a terminal and used the command `unity`.
3. Re-installing the removed packages, but to no avail.

[image: package manager]

OK. So now I have the desktop environment, but I just want to get into my desktop environment the regular way.

/var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[   613.670] 
X.Org X Server 1.12.3
Release Date: 2012-07-09
[   613.678] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   613.681] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-xen x86_64 Ubuntu
[   613.684] Current Operating System: Linux nick-N76VM 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013 x86_64
[   613.684] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   613.688] Build Date: 09 July 2012  05:20:18PM
[   613.690] xorg-server 2:1.12.3+git20120709+server-1.12-branch.60e0d205-0ubuntu0ricotz~precise (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   613.691] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[   613.693]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   613.693] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   613.698] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 25 22:44:37 2014
[   613.699] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   613.699] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   613.699] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   613.699] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   613.699] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[   613.700] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   613.700] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   613.700] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   613.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   613.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   613.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   613.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   613.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   613.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   613.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   613.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   613.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   613.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   613.700] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[   613.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   613.700] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   613.700] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   613.700] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   613.700] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fc26f685b00
[   613.700] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   613.700]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   613.700]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.0
[   613.700]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[   613.700]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[   613.700] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0166:1043:1477 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[   613.700] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0de9:1043:1477 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   613.700] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   613.700] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[   613.700] (II) "extmod" will be loaded by default.
[   613.700] (II) "dbe" will be loaded by default.
[   613.700] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   613.700] (II) "record" will be loaded by default.
[   613.700] (II) "dri" will be loaded by default.
[   613.700] (II) "dri2" will be loaded by default.
[   613.700] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[   613.700] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[   613.701] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.701]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   613.701]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   613.701]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[   613.701] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[   613.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[   613.701] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.701]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   613.701]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   613.701]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   613.701] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   613.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   613.701] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.701]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   613.701]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.701] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension GLX
[   613.701] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[   613.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[   613.701] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.701]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.13.0
[   613.701]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   613.701]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[   613.701] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[   613.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[   613.701] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.701]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   613.701]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[   613.701] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   613.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[   613.701] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.701]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.2.0
[   613.701]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.701] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[   613.701] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[   613.701] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[   613.701] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   613.701] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   613.701] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   613.702] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   613.702] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.702]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 2.99.906
[   613.702]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   613.702]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[   613.702] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   613.702] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   613.702] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   613.702] (II) Unloading vesa
[   613.702] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   613.702] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   613.702] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   613.702] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   613.702] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   613.702] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   613.702] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[   613.702] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[   613.702] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   613.702] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   613.702] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   613.702] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   613.702] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.702]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 2.99.906
[   613.702]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   613.702]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[   613.702] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[   613.702] (II) Unloading intel
[   613.702] (II) Failed to load module "intel" (already loaded, 32706)
[   613.702] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   613.702] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   613.702] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   613.702] (II) Unloading vesa
[   613.702] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   613.702] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   613.703] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   613.703] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   613.703] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   613.703] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   613.703] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   613.703] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-5000
[   613.703] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100
[   613.703] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200
[   613.703] (--) using VT number 8

[   613.707] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[   613.707] drmOpenDevice: open result is 8, (OK)
[   613.707] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
[   613.707] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[   613.707] drmOpenDevice: open result is 8, (OK)
[   613.707] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 8
[   613.707] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:02.0
[   613.707] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise (Robert Hooker )
[   613.707] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
[   613.707] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx
[   613.707] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   613.707] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   613.707] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[   613.707] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   613.708] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[   613.708] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[   613.708] (**) intel(0): "Tear free" disabled
[   613.708] (**) intel(0): Forcing per-crtc-pixmaps? no
[   613.708] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[   613.708] (--) intel(0): found backlight control interface acpi_video1 (type 'firmware')
[   613.708] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[   613.708] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[   613.708] (--) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1920x1080 on pipe 0
[   613.708] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   613.708] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   613.708] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   613.708] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[   613.708] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.708]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.2.0
[   613.708]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   613.708] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   613.709] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Ivybridge (gen7, gt2) backend
[   613.709] (==) intel(0): Backing store disabled
[   613.709] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   613.709] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[   613.709] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[   613.709] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[   613.709] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   613.709] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[   613.709] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
[   613.709] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
[   613.709] (--) RandR disabled
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   613.709] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   613.710] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   613.710] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   613.710] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   613.710] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   613.710] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   613.724] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[   613.724] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[   613.724] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[   613.724] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[   613.724] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[   613.724] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[   613.726] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[   613.748] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[   613.760] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /tmp/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   613.762] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   613.762] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.762] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[   613.762] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   613.762] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.762]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 2.7.0
[   613.762]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   613.762]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[   613.762] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   613.762] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   613.762] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[   613.762] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   613.762] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   613.762] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.762] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   613.762] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   613.762] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.762] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.762] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.762] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.764] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /tmp/server-A5431D4A34463C892C9E905E2E421B30A3CC30DD.xkm
[   613.764] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[   613.764] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.764] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[   613.764] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   613.764] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[   613.764] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   613.764] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[   613.764] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.764] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input5/event5"
[   613.764] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   613.764] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.764] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.764] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.764] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.765] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event4)
[   613.765] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.765] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[   613.765] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   613.765] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[   613.765] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   613.765] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[   613.765] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.765] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4/event4"
[   613.765] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.765] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[   613.765] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   613.765] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   613.765] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   613.765] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.765] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[   613.765] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[   613.765] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[   613.765] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[   613.765] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[   613.765] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.765] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[   613.765] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.765] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.766] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ASUS USB2.0 Webcam (/dev/input/event10)
[   613.766] (**) ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.766] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ASUS USB2.0 Webcam'
[   613.766] (**) ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: always reports core events
[   613.766] (**) evdev: ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: Device: "/dev/input/event10"
[   613.766] (--) evdev: ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: Vendor 0x1bcf Product 0x2883
[   613.766] (--) evdev: ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: Found keys
[   613.766] (II) evdev: ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.766] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input10/event10"
[   613.766] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ASUS USB2.0 Webcam" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.766] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[   613.766] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   613.766] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   613.766] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event8)
[   613.766] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   613.766] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   613.766] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[   613.766] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.766] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Asus WMI hotkeys'
[   613.766] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[   613.766] (**) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[   613.766] (--) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[   613.766] (--) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[   613.766] (II) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.766] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input6/event6"
[   613.766] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.766] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.767] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   613.767] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   613.767] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   613.767] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   613.767] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[   613.767] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[   613.767] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[   613.767] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   613.767] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[   613.767] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   613.767] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   613.767] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   613.767] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   613.767] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   613.767] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event9)
[   613.767] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[   613.767] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[   613.767] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[   613.767] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[   613.767] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[   613.767] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   613.767]    compiled for 1.12.3, module version = 1.6.99
[   613.767]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   613.767]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[   613.767] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[   613.767] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[   613.767] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[   613.768] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: found clickpad property
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3420
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 2052
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[   613.768] (**) Option "TapButton1" "1"
[   613.768] (**) Option "TapButton2" "2"
[   613.768] (**) Option "TapButton3" "3"
[   613.768] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[   613.768] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[   613.768] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input9/event9"
[   613.768] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[   613.768] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[   613.768] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[   613.768] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.050
[   613.768] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   613.768] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[   613.768] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   613.768] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   613.768] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[   613.768] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   613.768] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[   613.971] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "CMO", prod id 5920
[   613.971] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   613.971] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  140.49  1920 1972 2007 2094  1080 1083 1089 1118 +hsync -vsync (67.1 kHz eP)
[   613.971] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   92.45  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (44.4 kHz e)
[   800.912] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /tmp/server-66EE0154F48ACA3B8B41E2DABCBEB27CFFFED199.xkm
[  2376.191] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  2376.566] (II) PM Event received: Capability Changed
[  2376.566] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  2378.696] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  2383.590] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  2383.590] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[  2383.590] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  2383.629] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  3287.521] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  3287.881] (II) PM Event received: Capability Changed
[  3287.881] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  3289.708] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  3294.597] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  3294.597] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[  3294.597] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  3294.645] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  3304.812] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[  3304.812] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.813] (II) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.813] (II) evdev: ASUS USB2.0 Webcam: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.813] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.813] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.813] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.813] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  3304.813] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3304.864]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[  3304.864] Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

UPDATE:
GDM works, opened terminal and entered command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and rebooted. Xorg started as well as Unity, But I want the Unity GUI. Until I find a way to do that I will stick with this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention I re-installed them. See my edit please

Comment: I just replaced the old one with the newest log. Which log file would be better?

Comment: And yes, that's correct. No login screen

Comment: I put the results of `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log` in my question. I guess it wouldn't hurt to follow your suggestion to reinstall `unity-greeter` and/or reconfigure `unity-greeter`

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. I didn't know about this tool, thank you. The log from lightdm is from 8 hours ago. re-install and reconfigure didn't work.

Comment: I have the following logs: Jan 25 22:34 console-setup.log .. Jan 25 22:34 container-detect.log .. Jan 25 22:35 cryptdisks-enable.log .. Jan 25 22:34 cups.log .. Jan 25 22:34 dbus.log .. Jan 25 22:34 hybrid-gfx.log .. Jan 25 22:34 module-init-tools.log .. Jan 25 22:34 procps-virtual-filesystems.log .. Jan 25 22:34 rsyslog.log .. Jan 25 22:34 ureadahead.log .. Jan 25 22:34 ureadahead-other.log

Comment: Ok, I found it, it had a timestamp that is written as we speak so I'm pretty sure it's recent as they come. What exactly am I looking for? (edited the post)

Comment: Edited the question, it now contains the 'relevant' log

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to capture that info. The key I used is <kbd>esc</kbd> which shows me what happens at boot.

Comment: Please look at this Q&A. I think this is your problem and the solution for it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/74551/lightdm-not-starting-on-boot If it is, we just clear up this lot of comments and close this as a duplicate of that one. Please report back if the solution presented there works for you.

Comment: Thank you @falconer, This solved the issue. Don't know why I couldn't find it before but you have my grattitude for all of your time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

1. Open terminal
2. enter `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` followed by password when prompted
3. enter `sudo reboot` and enter password when prompted
   Everything works. No Unity-greeter though