# Fluxbox configuration on Ubuntu 14.04 mini iso installed on EXT-BT board

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, fluxbox

I am working on a ETX-BT Atom board. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 with "mini.iso" using the Unetbootin utility. Now Ubuntu is running fine.

I am trying to configure the GUI interface to use a window manger.

I am trying to configure Fluxbox, but I'm unable to run it.

I am getting the below error when I run `/usr/bin/fluxbox`:

```
Error: Couldn't connect to Xserver passing Null Display
```

Could you please share your suggestions or inputs to solve this problem?

Comment: I've removed the additional questions, please ask only one question at the time; of course you're free to ask other questions about the other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install  software-properties-common
apt-get dist-upgrade

apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xfonts-base xinit x11-xserver-utils x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils xinput xorg lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter oxygen-icon-theme flashplugin-installer gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libcurl3 libnotify4 libtag1-vanilla dkms gvfs gvfs-backends policykit-1 udisks2 synaptic fluxbox fluxconf idesk rox-filer

dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Edited: Minimal fluxbox install

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install xorg gvfs gvfs-backends policykit-1 udisks2 fluxbox fluxconf idesk rox-filer
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: I'm having ubuntu 14.04 which is running on embedded application and i may get into memory problems after installing all this packages. Could you please share the list of minimal packages that do i need to install to get fluxbox working?

Comment: When i tried installing fluxconf on ubuntu 14.04. it apt-get gives an Error:  E :unable to locate package fluxconf

Comment: Install other packages and download this from: http://fluxbox.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: How to make sure the current window setting is fluxbox?   I'm able to get one GUI window for login, but unable to login.

Comment: I am able to run fluxbox with default ubunt 14.04 with linux kernel 3.13-x. Appreciate your help.. :) How to make flux box as a default login session.

Comment: Try install lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter.

Comment: I am able to install lightdm and able to login through. I added new file  .conf to lightdm conf demon directory for enabling auto login. I was able to get the same working. But now i am unable to get same behaviour, login window is waiting for authentication. when i entered password, it is throwing authentication failure message. Any Idea?

Comment: There are many issues that require differents posts.

Comment: I want to use below steps which has gdm instead of lightdm.                                                                                                    apt-get install xserver-xorg  gdm  fluxbox                                                           reboot                                                                                                                                                                                                                         with above minimal steps unable to get fluxbox.                                       Any idea what is missing?

Comment: gvfs gvfs-backends policykit-1 udisks idesk rox-filer are these packages mandatory?

Comment: No, these packages are not mandatory.

Comment: Instead of lightdm can i use gdm?                                                                    Please share package details for fluxbox configuration using gdm.

Comment: lightdm startup configuration not able to start application automatically. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Read here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/74551/lightdm-not-starting-on-boot

Comment: I do not have nVidia Card. I'm running it on ETX-BT embedded board. Any idea?