# LightDM GUI fails in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, gui

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 computer running . Yesterday, I was trying to install Teamviewer, but I was not able because apparently it depended "on libgcc1". After doing some search, a specialized forum indicated that the problem could be solved by installing Wine, and I did so. Unfortunately, it seems that the installation of this program messed up with the configuration of the system, as when I turned on the computer again, I was able to access the GRUB prompt but the screen would go black afterwards. After some analysis, I realised it was due to the fact that "Starting LightDM Display Manager" was failing, and thus the GUI was not starting. Does anyone know how to fix the issue? I'm a beginner in Ubuntu and I don't want to make it worse. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose  `kdm` as default.

If this doesn´t work, try with other answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74551/lightdm-not-starting-on-boot).

PS: As you said you´re new on Ubuntu, I recommended you to download **.deb** files when you want to install something new on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Please do not post an answer containing only links to other Ask Ubuntu posts. If you think the other linked question asks about the same problem, flag it as duplicate. Otherwise please include at least the most important steps into your own answer and only add the link as reference. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: No need to be sorry, we all were new to this site and unfamiliar with its rules once. Just try to improve your answer a bit and everything is fine :)