# Have to start lightdm manually on startup

Tags: dual-boot, lightdm

I have a dual boot machine. Whenever I try to boot into Ubuntu, I have to manually startup lightdm by entering `sudo start lightdm` in the tty.

I already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74551/lightdm-not-starting-on-boot) method.

The terminal shows `/usr/sbin/lightdm` when I enter `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` in it.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu16.04

Comment: In that case please [edit] your question to include the output of `systemctl status lightdm.service`

Comment: When I run the above command on terminal it says: Failed to get properties: No such interface ''