# Ubuntu 18.04 stopped booting into GUI

Tags: boot, xfce

I tried to clean some packages up and wound up screwing something up.

Now, it no longer boots to a graphic window:  I get a terminal login screen.

I'm using `xfce4` and I *can* use the `startx` command to enter the graphical environment, but I'd prefer to go straight to a graphic login, user-screen and so on.

Ubuntu 18.04 latest.

Answer (score 0):

Clean away the wreckage of the old Desktop Environment before reinstalling xfce by

```
sudo apt purge  '~n^libxfce4.*' '~n^libexo.*' '~n^libgarcon.*'
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I don't want to use all of "xubuntu-desktop" just "xfce4."  The `apt purge` you listed didn't find anything to purge.  But things like *libxfce4* did.  Trying it now.  (what appears as italics is string enclosed by asterisks)

Comment: Excellent! Hope you will post your own answer here, as it would be far superior to mine.

Comment: I'm letting it do the xubuntu-desktop install after all.  Man, that's a lot of software!

Comment: It still doesn't boot into a GUI.  Note however that `systemctl get-default` does return `graphical.target!`  So it seems to me that it's *supposed to* be going GUI!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out *what* was going wrong but not *why.*

In `/var/log/syslog` I see:

```
 lightdm.service Main process exited, coe=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 lightdm.service failed with result 'exit-code'
```

I then followed the suggestion given here ... [Lightdm not starting on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74551/lightdm-not-starting-on-boot) ...

... and used the `dpkg-reconfigure` command to choose `gdm3`.

Magically, it worked!