# Icons have disappeared from XFCE4 launcher panel at bottom of screen

Tags: launcher, icons, xfce

On my XFCE4 installation, I see the launcher panel at the bottom of the screen but all of the icons have disappeared ... terminal, web browser, and so on.  They are set to launch the right things but the usual icons are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting ... when I switched from `lightdm` to `gdm3` in response to my ...

[Ubuntu 18.04 stopped booting into GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213241/ubuntu-18-04-stopped-booting-into-gui)

... this problem disappeared, too!